# CAML query display items in list that users are in group and assigned to

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

I am trying to have the items listed to users based on their assigned group and when specifically assigned to. I have a group field and an AssignTo field. Users can be in 1 or more group. Other users from the same group should not see the item that is not assigned to them.

The following query display the items for groups

```
<Where>
    <Or>
        <Membership Type='CurrentUserGroups'>
            <FieldRef Name='Group' />
        </Membership>
        <Includes>
            <FieldRef Name='Group' />
            <Value Type='Integer'>
                <UserID Type='Integer' />
            </Value>
        </Includes>
    </Or>
</Where>
```

and this one when user is specifically assigned

````
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name="Assigned_x0020_To" />
        <Value Type="Integer">
            <UserID Type="Integer" />
        </Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>

```


but it doesn't work when I combine them.
````